# Using Fetch with ReactJS

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I'm pretty new to ReactJS so this is my implementation of using Fetch inside of it.

```
class App extends React.Component {
  function postData(url, data) {
      // Default options are marked with *
      return fetch(url, {
        body: JSON.stringify(data), // must match 'Content-Type' header
        cache: 'no-cache', // *default, no-cache, reload, force-cache, only-if-cached
        credentials: 'same-origin', // include, same-origin, *omit
        headers: {
          'user-agent': 'Mozilla/4.0 MDN Example',
          'content-type': 'application/json'
        },
        method: 'POST', // *GET, POST, PUT, DELETE, etc.
        mode: 'cors', // no-cors, cors, *same-origin
        redirect: 'follow', // manual, *follow, error
        referrer: 'no-referrer', // *client, no-referrer
      })
      .then(response => response.json()) // parses response to JSON
    }


  render() {
    const test_content = ["first", "second", "third"];

    const initial_data = {
      'id': 1,
      'model-name': 'Joke'
    };

    postData('/start-jokes/', initial_data)
      .then(data => console.log(data)
       ) // JSON from `response.json()` call
      .catch(error => console.error(error));


    const jokes_div = test_content.map((item, i) => (
      <div key={i} className="card col-md-7">
        <div className="card-body">
            {item}
        </div>
      </div>
    ));
    return <div className="container" id="jokes">{jokes_div}</div>;
  }
}
// ========================================

ReactDOM.render(
  <App />,
  document.getElementById('root')
);
```

This works ok and the console logs this response.

```
Object { status: "ok", jokes: Array[10], ref-id: 11 }
```

The jokes array has an id and text in an Object, the text would be used same as `test_content` to populate the items with it's own unique key `id` shown here

[image]

any pointers on how to now populate from there will be much appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

Never call the api in render. If you want the data to be loaded when the page renders call the function in the componentDidMount ; else if you want to load on some other events or some input change call it in onChange event and as said no need to return the results you can setState the response.

```
class App extends React.Component {
    constructor(props) {
       super(props);
       this.state = { 
           data : [],
        }
     }
    componentDidMount(){
     this.postdata()
    }

    postdata(){
        var self = this;
            fetch(url, {
            body: JSON.stringify(data),
            cache: 'no-cache', 
            credentials: 'same-origin', 
            headers: {
            'user-agent': 'Mozilla/4.0 MDN Example',
            'content-type': 'application/json'
            },
            method: 'POST',
            mode: 'cors', 
            redirect: 'follow',
            referrer: 'no-referrer',
            })
            .then(response => response.json()).then((json) => {
              self.setState({ data : json.data }) // which ever the key hold the data 
            })
    }

    render(){
       return( 
            <div>
            {this.state.data.length == 0 && 
               <div> No options available.</div>
            }
            {this.state.data.length > 0 && 
              <div className="container" id="jokes">
                   {this.state.data.map(function(item,i){
                          return(
                                <div key={i} className="card col-md-7">
                                <div className="card-body">
                                {item}   // here you are getting object in item. Get the key from the object like item.name
                                </div>
                                </div>
                      )
                   })}
               </div>
            }
          </div>
         )
    }
}
```

Comment: it throws this error ```SyntaxError: http://35.196.142.180/static/js/react-script.js: Unexpected token (7:23)
   5 |            data : [],
   6 |         }
>  7 |     componentDidMount(){
     |                        ^
   8 |      this.postdata()
   9 |     }
  10 | ```

Comment: @SamuelM. please check now i have updated the code. Forgot to close the parenthesis of constructor

Comment: sorry to have to point out another bug ```SyntaxError: http://35.196.142.180/static/js/react-script.js: Unexpected token (34:17)
  32 |     render(){
  33 |        return( 
> 34 |             {this.state.data.length == 0 && 
     |                  ^
  35 |                <div> No options available.</div>
  36 |             }
  37 |             {this.state.data.length > 0 && ```

Comment: @SamuelM. please check now i have updated the code. Just wrap the return in <div> tag

Comment: think it's almost working... it throws an error for a missing value `ReferenceError: url is not defined`

Comment: @SamuelM.  in fetch in place of url  enter the api url .  fetch(url  // API url , {
            body: JSON.stringify(data),

Comment: ```SyntaxError: http://35.196.142.180/static/js/react-script.js: Unterminated string constant (14:18)
  12 |     postdata(){
  13 |         var self = this;
> 14 |             fetch('\/start-jokes\', {
     |                   ^
  15 |             body: JSON.stringify(data),
  16 |             cache: 'no-cache', 
  17 |             credentials: 'same-origin', ```

Comment: that was the error from this implementation `fetch('\/start-jokes\', {`

Comment: I put the back tick at the front not the end... Now it's throwing this error `ReferenceError: data is not defined`

Comment: Instead of `self.setState({ data : json.data })` try `self.setState({ data : json })`

Comment: it was for the initial json send `data` provided it with content now getting this `TypeError: this.state.data is undefined`

Answer (score 0):

As you're asynchronous, you'll need to take the lifecycle into account:

1. call postData in componentDidMount
2. instead of `.then(response => response.json())` set the result into the state, e.g. `.then(response => this.setState({jokes: response.json()}))`
3. in render, instead of test_content, use `(this.state.jokes || [])`

In larger applications, I'd consider separating rendering and data management (i.e. do two components), but I hope you get one step further with the points above...

Comment: Tried it this way, got an interesting bug https://pastebin.com/AsDKHjw5 not sure if it's because of how I used setState. The code now looks like this https://pastebin.com/ZBv9EXit